# GameDev "Tour" - factual error

Tags: support

This morning I misclicked the "tour" option instead of logging in, and noticed that, though SE has switched to the "on hold" closing system instead of an actual "close"ing system, the tour still says that questions may be closed. Is this in error?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions are still closed, they're just named differently for the first five days. The only other difference is edits made to an on hold question put it in the re-open queue), otherwise closed and on-hold are the same. However, the name change helps people understand that there's still a chance to fix the question.

I suppose we could change the text to read something like:

> Questions that need improvement may be put on hold until fixed, questions that are not fixed will be closed automatically after five days. 'On hold' and 'closed' questions cannot receive new answers.

While technically they're closed right away, this wording helps people understand that questions can be fixed and they should try to do so before they're "closed".